# How to use the php fopen() correctly

Tags: php

I am learning php, trying to use the `fopen()` function.
The php file I am coding is in this directory `/domains/xxxxx.com.au/public_html/phpfile.php`
What path do I specify for the file to be opened, the example I am looking at is based on a server on a pc where this is the file path `$filename = "c:/newfile.txt";` not an online server.

UPDATE!

This is the whole script, I have the file location correct, now the4 script is returning "couldnt create the file" does this have something to do with ther permission of the folder location of the file?

```
   <?php
$filename = "/domains/xxxxxxxx.com.au/public_html/newfile.txt";
$newfile = @fopen($filename, "w+") or die ("couldnt create the file");
fclose($newfile);
$msg = "<p>File Created</p>";
?>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<? echo "$msg" ?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you trying to open a text file on your local PC from an online server?

Comment: from an online server, I dont know how to formatt the file path. e.g. is it "public_html/phpfile.php" or "/domains/xxxxx.com.au/public_html/phpfile.php"

Comment: Why not to give a real example of the file you want to open?

Comment: You don't have write permissions to /domains/xxxxxxxx.com.au/public_html/ probably, you should chmod that directory or use a path you can write to :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your php file is inside the public_html too, you could use :

```
$fp = fopen( "newfile.txt", "rt" );
```

Or, giving the full path :

```
$fp = fopen( "/domains/xxxxx.com.au/public_html/newfile.txt", "rt" );
```

This will open it if it already exists.

Refer to [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for further details of opening flags.

UPDATE:
You can even use the [is_writable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)/[is_readable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) function to check file access before trying to open it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, please look at the edited question more problems (storey of my coding life)

Comment: What is "t" mode? It doesn't exist according to php docs.

Answer (score 1):

Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php  Example #1 is relevant for a Unix system.