# which variable is correct to parse into the fopen function

Tags: php

I have a problem in file opening syntax.I need to be clarified whether $a,$b and $c are same. I have to parse this variable to fopen function so which is correct?

```
fopen("path","mode");
```

Below are the variables,which should come in the place of path parameter in fopen function?

```
$filename= test.txt;

$a="$filename";

$b="test.txt";

$c= "\"".$filename."\"";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the php fopen() correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644861/how-to-use-the-php-fopen-correctly)

Comment: Actually,am not getting the answer from "How to use the php fopen() correctly" question. just I need to know whether $a,$b,$c are same

Comment: Why not `$filename="test.txt";`? I mean what type is `test.txt` supposed to have?

Comment: I have not problem in type of file..just with " " quotes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here. I assume you are trying to develop in PHP.

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r"); // for reading
```

Please note, store the filename as a string in a variable. You don't need to store $variable into another variable to pass it into fopen. But if you insist of using it, go with option a without the brackets:

```
$filename = "test.txt";
$a = $filename;
fopen($a, "r"); // for reading
```

Your given options are different.

Comment: Am getting the file path from mysql database,So I will get it in a $filename variable its not having "" quotes with it,I have to parse that path into fopen function,So inside the fopen function if I give "$filename" like dis, am not getting the file open so problem with "" quotes so that I have asked whether $a,$b,$c are same or not

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about this is specific to `fopen`. It simply expects both parameters to be a string. There are various methods how to pass a string, all equivalent:

```
$path = '/foo/bar';
fopen($path);

$path = "/foo/bar";
fopen($path);

$path = <<<PATH
/foo/bar
PATH;
fopen($path);

$path = '/foo' . '/bar';
fopen($path);

$path = '/' . join('/', array('foo', 'bar'));
fopen($path);

fopen('/foo/bar');
```

And a gazillion more equivalent ways of creating and passing a string.
The same applies to the second `mode` parameter.

---

```
$path = '/foo/bar';
$path = "$path";
```

This works fine, but is entirely superfluous. `"$path"` simply creates a new string with the value of `$path` interpolated, which in this case does nothing.

```
$path = "\"".$path."\"";
```

This is purely nonsense. You're just adding quotes to your existing string, which you don't want.

```
$path = test.txt;
```

This is an error and you'd see a warning if you'd enable error reporting. It'll create the string "testtxt". It'll look for the *constants* `test` and `txt` to concatenate `.` them, but not finding them it'll concatenate the strings `'test'` and `'txt'` instead.

Comment: If your variable stores a string, that's already fine. `$path = getFromDatabase(); fopen($path);` You only need quotes if you are writing a *string literal* in your source code file. If you get your strings from elsewhere, there's no need to add quotes!

Comment: Am getting the filepath from database so its without double quotes,just I stored that filepath into a variable so now how to parse that variable into the fopen function. example:             $file=test.txt;       fopen("$file","r");  is it correct?? But am not getting the file open, So am thinking the problem with double quotes

Comment: So if `$path= filepath`;then `fopen($path,'r')` is enough?

Comment: I don't know what exactly `filepath` is supposed to be, but if it's a string then yes.

Comment: It is a string but its giving an error that the filepath cannot be empty